# How to read latest SMS from all contacts efficiently?

Tags: android

I am trying to read latest SMS from All contacts but the procedure Currently I am using seems to be very slow. How can I improve it?

```
public Map<String, SMS> getLatestMsgs(){

    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    String[] projection = {_id, address, body,
            read, date, subscriptionId, type};
    String selection = "";
    String[] selectionArgs = {};
    String sortOrder = Telephony.Sms.DATE +" desc";

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(uriSMSURI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    LinkedHashMap<String, SMS> smsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    log.info(methodName, "Reading Messages..");
    if(c==null){
        log.info(methodName, "Query returned null cursor");
        return smsMap;
    }

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(this._id));
        String from = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(this.address));
        String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(this.body));
        int serviceCenter = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(this.subscriptionId));
        boolean readState = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(this.read)) == 1;
        long time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(this.date));
        long type = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(this.type));

        if(!smsMap.containsKey(from)) {
            SMS sms = new SMS();
            sms.setId(id);
            sms.setFrom(from);
            sms.setBody(body);
            sms.setRead(readState);
            sms.setDateTime(time);
            sms.setType(type);
            sms.setSubscription(serviceCenter);

            smsMap.put(from, sms);
        }

    }
    c.close();

    return smsMap;
}
```

This method has following steps:

> 1. Read all sms in decreasing order of timestamp
> 2. Start Iterating over fetched rows
>
>    - If sms address already in map then ignore
>    - else put SMS into LinkedHashMap

Comment: Initially I thought to do it using Group By clause but I need other parameter like read_state, _id, etc. thus we cannot apply Group By, and I am not able to think of any other way out

Comment: Yes, Conversations is working pretty good. But I don't have access to Date, SMS_type and Subscription. How can I can get that for latest SMS of a contact

Comment: I tried appending thread_id after conversations uri and iterating all conversations. So, now it is taking much longer now because of multiple access to data which made it much slower than before.